# Corona several transition.to gets out of phase

Tags: coronasdk

I am creating several display objects and using transition.to to move them horizontally. Everything works except the objects x positions get out of phase/position. The objects should have the same X positions forever but the longer it runs, the further out of position they get.

```
local function onLoopXListener( )
    transition.to( platform, { time=2000, x=0, transition=easing.inOutSine, delay=0} );
    transition.to( platform, { time=2000, x=320, transition=easing.inOutSine, delay=2000, onComplete=onLoopXListener} );
end

local function StartTransition( )
    transition.to( platform, { time=2000, x=0, transition=easing.inOutSine, delay=1000 } ); 
    transition.to( platform, { time=2000, x=320, transition=easing.inOutSine,  delay=3000, onComplete=onLoopXListener} );
end

for i = 1, 4, 1 do
    --create a new platform displayobject
    --seperate it vertically
    StartTransition( )
end
```

Forgive me if my code is ugly (I've removed irrelevant code - it all works except the positions) - it's the transition concept that I'm asking about here.

Comment: If it is possible create display group, add all objects to it and move group itself instead of each object separately.

Comment: good idea but I can't. The objects move independent to each other. I had them at the same X so I could easily compare their positions so I could tell if I fixed it.

Comment: May be use [`entereFrame`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/index.html) listener to control position of all objects. See also [Tutorial: Animation with “enterFrame” listeners](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/08/25/tutorial-animation-with-enterframe-listeners/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used "enterFrame" and it works fine. Here is my implementation:

```
local _lastTime = 0
local function OnEnterFrame( event )
    deltaTime = event.time - _lastTime
    _lastTime = event.time
    MoveMyPlatformOnEnterFrame(deltaTime)
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", OnEnterFrame )
```

This is how I implemented the sin() transition: 
Remember this needs to go above the function call.

```
local _loopTime  = someValue
local _xRadians =0
local _amplitude = someOtherValue
local _platform --this is the Display Object I want to move
function MoveMyPlatformOnEnterFrame( deltaTime )
    delta = deltaTime / _loopTime * (44/7)
    _xRadians = _xRadians + delta
    _xRadians = math.fmod( _xRadians, (44/7) )
    _platform.x = _position.x + math.sin( _xRadians ) * _amplitude
end
```